# Define custom conversion for structuremap to register Commands, CommandHandlers automatically

Tags: c#, registry, structuremap, cqrs

I'm using `CQRS` pattern in my recent project, so I defined some `Commands` that I call them `CommandParameter` and `CommandHandlers`.

For `CommandParameters` I have these `Class`es and `Interface`s:

```
public interface ICommandParameter
{
}

public abstract class BaseEntityCommandParameter<T> : IAggregateRoot,ICommandParameter
    where T : ModelEntitySuperType, new()
{
    public T Entity { get; set; }

    protected BaseEntityCommandParameter()
    {
        Entity = new T();
    }
}

public class InsertCommandParameter<T> : BaseEntityCommandParameter<T>
    where T : class, new()
{
}
```

And for `CommandHandlers` I defined these `Class`es and `Interface`s:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommandParameter>
    where TCommandParameter :ICommandParameter
{
    void Handle(TCommandParameter parameter);
    string CommandCode { get; }
}

public class InsertCommandHandler<TCommandParameter, TEntity> 
    : ICommandHandler<TCommandParameter>
    where TCommandParameter : BaseEntityCommandParameter<TEntity>, new()
    where TEntity : ModelEntitySuperType, IAggregateRoot, new()
```

and I used them to make appropriate `CommandParameter`s and `CommandHandler`s for each `Entity` for example for `Order` I have:

```
public class OrderInsertCommandParameter:InsertCommandParameter<Order>
{
}

public class OrderInsertCommandHandler 
    : InsertCommandHandler<OrderInsertCommandParameter, Order>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _factory;

    public OrderInsertCommandHandler(IUnitOfWorkFactory factory,
        IRepository<Order> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public override void Handle(OrderInsertCommandParameter parameter)
    {
        var uow = _factory.Create();
        parameter.Entity.OrderCreationTime = DateTime.Now;
        base.Handle(parameter);
        uow.Commit();
    }
}
```

I want to register these `CommandParameter`s and appropriate `CommandHandler`s using `structuremap` automatically, How could I define a custom Conversion to do this?

Comment: You don't register `CommandParameter` classes, since they are not services. They are messages, simple data packages (DTOs) that are sent through the services. Your `CommandHandler`s are the services. You need to register them.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
container.Configure(r => 
{ 
    r.Scan(s => 
    { 
        s.Assembly(typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly);
        s.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)); 
    }); 
});
```